# Swift quiz app how to go on the next question?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm new to Swift. I'm trying to make a quiz app using the API, I can show a question and answers, but I can't move on to the next questions. I can access different questions in the api with the index, but when I click on the options, I can't go to the next question. I looked at similar applications and watched a few how to make quiz app videos from youtube, but I couldn't do it.

my QuizManager

```
import Foundation

protocol quizManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateQuiz(_ Quizmanager: QuizManager ,quiz: QuizModel)
}

struct QuizManager {
    
    var index : Int  = 0
    var maxQuestion = 14

    
    mutating func nextQuestion(result: Bool) -> Int{
        if result == true{
          return  index + 1
        } else {
            return index
        }
        
    }
    

    
    var delegate: quizManagerDelegate?
    
    func performRequest(){
        
         let urlString = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=15&type=multiple"        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data{
                                        
                    if let quiz = self.parseJSON(quizdata: safeData){
                        delegate?.didUpdateQuiz(self, quiz: quiz)
                        

                    }
                    
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func handle(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void {
        
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(quizdata: Data) -> QuizModel? {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do{
            
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: quizdata)
            
            let correct = decodedData.results?[index].correct_answer ?? "error"
            let quest = decodedData.results?[index].question ?? "error"
            let incorrect = decodedData.results?[index].incorrect_answers ?? ["error"]
            let question = QuizModel(correctAnswer: correct, question: quest, falseAnswer: incorrect)
     
            return question
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    mutating func nextQuestion(){
        
        if index + 1 < maxQuestion {
            index += 1
        }else {
            index = 0
            
        }
    }

}
```

my QuizData

```
import Foundation


 // MARK: - Welcome
 struct Welcome: Codable {
 let results: [Result]?
 }
 
 // MARK: - Result
 struct Result: Codable {
     
 let category: String?
 let question, correct_answer: String?
 let incorrect_answers: [String]?
 }
```

my QuizModel

```
import Foundation

struct QuizModel {
    
    let correctAnswer : String
    let question : String
    let falseAnswer : [String]
}
```

my ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionTextView: UITextView!
    
    var quizMangager = QuizManager()
    var score = 0
    
    var theQuiz: QuizModel?
   
    @IBAction func OptionsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        guard let thisQuiz = theQuiz,
                  let btnTitle = sender.currentTitle
            else { return }
            
            if btnTitle == thisQuiz.correctAnswer {
                score += 1
                ScoreLabel.text = "SCORE: \(score)"
                quizMangager.nextQuestion()
                
                sender.setTitleColor(.systemGreen, for: [])
                
            } else {
                sender.setTitleColor(.systemRed, for: [])
                quizMangager.nextQuestion()
            }
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.35, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
        QuestionTextView.text = thisQuiz.question   
        
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
    
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        QuestionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        quizMangager.delegate = self
        quizMangager.performRequest()
    }

}

extension ViewController : quizManagerDelegate{
    func didUpdateQuiz(_ Quizmanager: QuizManager, quiz: QuizModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            
            self.theQuiz = quiz

            self.QuestionTextView.text = quiz.question

            var allOptions = []
            allOptions.append(quiz.falseAnswer[0])
            allOptions.append(quiz.falseAnswer[1])
            allOptions.append(quiz.falseAnswer[2])
            allOptions.append(quiz.correctAnswer)
            
            let generatedValue = Array(allOptions.shuffled().prefix(4))
            print(generatedValue)
            print(quiz.correctAnswer)

            ChoiceButton1.setTitle(generatedValue[0] as? String, for: .normal)
            ChoiceButton2.setTitle(generatedValue[1] as? String, for: .normal)
            ChoiceButton3.setTitle(generatedValue[2] as? String, for: .normal)
            ChoiceButton4.setTitle(generatedValue[3] as? String, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a github example for easier debugger your problem?

Comment: @bewithyou https://github.com/mertplt/QuizApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are "new to Swift" I'll skip critique of your code... but a couple notes...

Since you are using the "new" `UIButton` styles, you should use the button configuration instead of `setTitle()` / `.setTitleColor()`, etc.

To "move on to the next question" add `quizManager.performRequest()` to your `updateUI()` function.

Take a look at this modified version of your `ViewController` class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChoiceButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionTextView: UITextView!
    
    var quizMangager = QuizManager()
    var score = 0
    
    var theQuiz: QuizModel?
   
    @IBAction func OptionsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        guard let thisQuiz = theQuiz
        else { return }

        // disable buttons so user cannot tap more than one
        let btns: [UIButton] = [ChoiceButton1, ChoiceButton2, ChoiceButton3, ChoiceButton4]
        btns.forEach { btn in
            btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }

        var cfg = sender.configuration
        
        if let btnTitle = cfg?.title {

            if btnTitle == thisQuiz.correctAnswer {
                score += 1
                ScoreLabel.text = "SCORE: \(score)"
                cfg?.baseForegroundColor = .systemGreen
            } else {
                cfg?.baseForegroundColor = .systemRed
            }

        }

        sender.configuration = cfg
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.35, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
    
        quizMangager.nextQuestion()
        quizMangager.performRequest()

    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        QuestionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        quizMangager.delegate = self
        quizMangager.performRequest()
    }

}

extension ViewController : quizManagerDelegate{
    func didUpdateQuiz(_ Quizmanager: QuizManager, quiz: QuizModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            
            self.theQuiz = quiz

            self.QuestionTextView.text = quiz.question

            var allOptions: [String] = []
            allOptions.append(quiz.falseAnswer[0])
            allOptions.append(quiz.falseAnswer[1])
            allOptions.append(quiz.falseAnswer[2])
            allOptions.append(quiz.correctAnswer)
            
            let generatedValue = Array(allOptions.shuffled().prefix(4))
            print(generatedValue)
            print(quiz.correctAnswer)

            let btns: [UIButton] = [ChoiceButton1, ChoiceButton2, ChoiceButton3, ChoiceButton4]
            
            // we want to reset buttons
            //  enabled and title color
            // and set the new titles
            for (str, btn) in zip(generatedValue, btns) {
                
                var cfg = btn.configuration
                cfg?.baseForegroundColor = .white
                cfg?.title = str
                btn.configuration = cfg
                btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of problems need to be solved.

I will explain as detail as possible and you will need to try it yourself.

First of all, you have `QuizManager` to control `Quiz` but you don't store QuizData here you delegate data back to `ViewController`. So when you update answer you call `quizMangager.nextQuestion()` is pointless because `QuizManager` don't control or has any data.

For this you first need to refactor your `QuizManager`.

- Change `protocol quizManagerDelegate` -> `protocol QuizManagerDelegate` for right naming convention.
- When you `performRequest` you get your `safeData` just parse one time and get the list Result. You can convert to list `QuizModel` if you like and save it in your `QuizManager`
- In `QuizManagerDelegate`, just notice to the view controller the quizModel in order for updating

```swift
protocol QuizManagerDelegate { 
    func didUpdateQuiz(quiz: QuizModel)
}
```

And in your `performRequest` code will be like this

```swift
self.parseJSON(quizdata: safeData)
delegate?.didUpdateQuiz(quiz:listQuizData[index]) // remember to check if has index

func parseJSON(quizdata: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: quizdata)
        let decodedResult = decodedData.results // list result
        // you can convert to list quizmodel and save it
        
        // If you do like this just get only one quizModel as each parseJson.
        let correct = decodedData.results?[index].correct_answer ?? "error" // remove
        let quest = decodedData.results?[index].question ?? "error" // remove
        let incorrect = decodedData.results?[index].incorrect_answers ?? ["error"] // remove
        let question = QuizModel(correctAnswer: correct, question: quest, falseAnswer: incorrect) // remove
 
        return question // remove
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

with `listQuizData` is the list result you parse and convert from `Json` in `performRequest`

- Final in your `nextQuestion` after you update the index just need to call `delegate?.didUpdateQuiz(quiz:listQuizData[index])`

Come to the `ViewController`
You just need to take the `QuizModel` and view it

```swift
func didUpdateQuiz(quiz: QuizModel) {
    self.theQuiz = quiz
    
    var allOptions : [String] = []
    allOptions.append(contentsOf: quiz.falseAnswer) // combine to append only one time
    allOptions.append(quiz.correctAnswer)
    
    let generatedValue = Array(allOptions.shuffled().prefix(4))
    print(generatedValue)
    print(quiz.correctAnswer)

    ChoiceButton1.setTitle(generatedValue[0], for: .normal)
    ChoiceButton2.setTitle(generatedValue[1], for: .normal)
    ChoiceButton3.setTitle(generatedValue[2], for: .normal)
    ChoiceButton4.setTitle(generatedValue[3], for: .normal)
}
```